# Translation of "I find my job exciting"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

> I find my job exciting.

Wie übersetzt man das ins Deutsche?

> Ich finde meine Arbeit aufregend.

Die [vorgeschlagenen Übersetzungen von *exciting*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-german/exciting) sind *aufregend*, *sensationell*, *reizvoll*, *spannend* und *erregend*. Ich finde, dass nur *aufregend* hier passen könnte. Und wenn man sich [die Übersetzungen von *aufregend*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufregend) im Duden anschaut, bekommt man ein Gefühl, dass sogar das eine Übertreibung sein könnte (zum Beispiel, wenn der Job nicht Bungeespringer, sondern Lehrer ist.) Passt das Wort eigentlich? Was sind andere Alternativen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im derzeitigen Gebrauch ist "spannend" die nächste Entsprechung; es bedeutet ebenfalls eigentlich "die Nerven erregend", ist aber durch übermäßigen Gebrauch bereits leicht verblaßt in Richtung "allgemein positiv wirkend".

Answer (score 2):

Aufregend passt am besten, vorausgesehen dass der Job wirklich "exciting" ist. Ansonsten würde ich sagen "mein Job ist nie langweilig".